# Ошибка java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

Код выдает ошибку

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0 at mass.Uporyadoc.main(Uporyadoc.java:34)

```
/* Дан массив из n элементов. Упорядочить массив по возрастанию */
package mass;

import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Uporyadoc {

    public static void sort(int [] a)
    {
        int i,j,n = 0,k;
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(j=i;j<n;j++){
                if (a[j]<a[i]){
                    k=a[j];
                    a[j]=a[i];
                    a[i]=k;
                }
            }
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
           out.println(a[i]+" ");
        out.println();
    }

    public static  void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(in);
        int i;
        int n = 0;
        int a[] = new int[n];
        out.println("Введите количество элементов: ");
        n = reader.nextInt();
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            a[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
            out.println("Вывод");
            sort(a);

    }
}
```

Comment: int a[] = new int[n]; и  n = reader.nextInt(); местами поменяйте хотя бы.

Comment: Я новичок:(Теперь ничего не выводит пустую строчку,зато та ошибка исчезла)

Comment: т.е пустую строчку выводит

Comment: а вы и не выводите ничего кроме слова "вывод"

Comment: упс.понятно,спасибо вам всем

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int n = 0;    
int a[] = new int[n];
```

Вы создаете массив длиной `0`. Потом, считываете с консоли число в переменную `n`:

```
n = reader.nextInt();
```

Но массив-то к этому моменту уже создан. Дальнейшее итерирование по массиву сразу выходит за пределы массива.

---

Кроме того, метод `sort()` не будет работать так, как вы ожидаете.

В самом начале вы объявляете `n = 0`:

```
 public static void sort(int [] a)
    {
        int i,j,n = 0,k;
```

и тут же начинаете цикл от `0` до `<n`. Замените `n = 0` на `n = a.length`.

Comment: Спасибо,работает)

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, вы абсолютно не понимаете, что именно делает приведенный вами код. Попробуйте сначала разобраться в основах работы с массивами. И ещё посмотрите, что такое сортировка выбором (или пузырьком) и как она работает.

```
public static void sort(int [] a) {
    int n = a.length; // получаем размерность массива a
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { // i<n - счетчик i должен быть меньше размерности массива a
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[j] < a[i]) {
                int k = a[j];
                a[j] = a[i];
                a[i] = k;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        out.println(a[i]+" ");
    out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(in);
    int n = 0;
    out.println("Введите количество элементов: ");
    n = reader.nextInt(); // сначала получаем значение n
    int a[] = new int[n]; // затем создаём массив размерностью n
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
    out.println("Вывод");
    sort(a);
}
```